# Split LAS data from multi-beam sensors

Tags: lidar, las, lidr, multibeam

I'm working with 4 different las datasets, each of which are produced by multi-beam sensors (Leica ALS70-HP and Riegl LMS 1560). In 2 of the datasets (Examples A, and C) the `UserData` field seems to indicate the beam that produced each point. However, the other 2 datasets (Examples B, and D) do not provide any distinction between beams. I have grouped the points by gpstime in the data snippets below. One problem is that these point groupings appear problematic  to the `lidR` package (and probably other las processing software) since the size of the `gpstime` group exceeds the `NumberOfReturns`. At first glance it seems possible to infer the beam groups by using the X&Y coords to group the data. Is there a more proven technique for separating B & D by beam? If so how?

Example A - Leica ALS70-HP sensor - `UserData` populated:

```
          gpstime         X          Y PointSourceID NumberOfReturns ReturnNumber UserData
1: 115044218.70199 538309.32 4888037.69           237               4            1        0
2: 115044218.70199 538309.93 4888037.54           237               4            2        0
3: 115044218.70199 538310.59 4888037.37           237               4            3        0
4: 115044218.70199 538311.40 4888037.17           237               4            4        0
5: 115044218.70199 538317.66 4888120.74           237               5            1        1
6: 115044218.70199 538318.32 4888120.76           237               5            2        1
7: 115044218.70199 538318.85 4888120.78           237               5            3        1
8: 115044218.70199 538319.42 4888120.80           237               5            4        1
9: 115044218.70199 538320.66 4888120.83           237               5            5        1
```

Example B - Leica ALS70-HP sensor - `UserData` unpopulated:

```
             gpstime         X          Y      Z PointSourceID NumberOfReturns ReturnNumber UserData
 1: 84657023.0276344 520315.34 4585665.49 210.01          3766               5            1        0
 2: 84657023.0276344 520313.89 4585665.53 203.44          3766               5            2        0
 3: 84657023.0276344 520312.86 4585665.56 198.82          3766               5            3        0
 4: 84657023.0276344 520311.73 4585665.60 193.70          3766               5            4        0
 5: 84657023.0276344 520310.08 4585665.65 186.21          3766               5            5        0
 6: 84657023.0276344 520302.44 4585735.63 174.22          3766               5            1        0
 7: 84657023.0276344 520300.69 4585736.00 166.41          3766               5            2        0
 8: 84657023.0276344 520299.52 4585736.24 161.20          3766               5            3        0
 9: 84657023.0276344 520298.07 4585736.55 154.72          3766               5            4        0
10: 84657023.0276344 520296.46 4585736.89 147.52          3766               5            5        0
```

Example C - Riegl LMS 1560 Sensor - `UserData` populated:

```
             gpstime         X          Y PointSourceID NumberOfReturns ReturnNumber UserData
1: 208537376.083127 356284.06 4755397.29            45               3            1       39
2: 208537376.083127 356291.24 4755398.51            45               3            2       39
3: 208537376.083127 356292.15 4755398.67            45               3            3       39
4: 208537376.083127 355887.28 4755176.24            45               6            1       38
5: 208537376.083127 355887.72 4755176.05            45               6            2       38
6: 208537376.083127 355887.86 4755175.99            45               6            3       38
7: 208537376.083127 355888.46 4755175.73            45               6            4       38
8: 208537376.083127 355889.04 4755175.47            45               6            5       38
9: 208537376.083127 355890.46 4755174.86            45               6            6       38
```

Example D - Riegl LMS 1560 Sensor - `UserData` unpopulated:

```
             gpstime         X          Y PointSourceID NumberOfReturns ReturnNumber UserData
 1: 144879439.825614 244971.50 4682963.72            35               7            1        0
 2: 144879439.825614 244971.42 4682964.04            35               7            2        0
 3: 144879439.825614 244971.15 4682965.15            35               7            3        0
 4: 144879439.825614 244971.04 4682965.65            35               7            4        0
 5: 144879439.825614 244970.95 4682966.03            35               7            5        0
 6: 144879439.825614 244970.82 4682966.56            35               7            6        0
 7: 144879439.825614 244970.70 4682967.08            35               7            7        0
 8: 144879439.825614 245142.05 4682975.79            35               7            1        0
 9: 144879439.825614 245142.13 4682976.37            35               7            2        0
10: 144879439.825614 245142.28 4682977.47            35               7            3        0
11: 144879439.825614 245142.31 4682977.72            35               7            4        0
12: 144879439.825614 245142.36 4682978.07            35               7            5        0
13: 144879439.825614 245142.40 4682978.40            35               7            6        0
14: 144879439.825614 245142.55 4682979.55            35               7            7        0
```

Comment: When you say beam number do you mean you want to separate the data by pulse? (i.e. each first return will represent a unique group)

Comment: @Kartograaf - sure. My understanding is that pulses are organized by matching `gpstime`s. The datasets above show returns corresponding to a unique `gpstime` (or pulse), but there are 2 first returns for each dataset which is problematic. Like I said, my guess is that there are two beams involved...  So yes, I would like there to be 1 first return per group. In datasets A and C, we can further group the data by the `UserData` field to achieve 1 first return per group, however we can't do this for datasets B and D.

Comment: Interesting question. The dataset seems sorted by gpstime and return number (if not sort it). You can loop through the pulse (gpstime) and compute if the previous return number is lesser than the next one. If not, it is new beam. Something like `las@data[, UserData := cumsum(c(0L, diff(ReturnNumber)) <= 0L), by = gpstime)`. I will be able to try it myself later.

Comment: I think the issue could be due to what Leica refers to as 'multiple output scanning system' in the user manual (top left corner page 4) http://w3.leica-geosystems.com/downloads123/zz/airborne/ALS70/brochures/Leica_ALS70_6P_BRO_en.pdf although the Reigl scanner does have two lasers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. I didn't know about such device. This is a difficult question and I though about it and it is probably impossible to retrieve the actual beams in the general case. However if we assume that the points are correctly ordered by gpstime, then beam, then return number we can retrieve the beams with:

```r
las@data[, UserData := cumsum(c(0, diff(ReturnNumber)) <= 0) -1, by = gpstime]
```

But if the points are not ordered it is no longer possible. In your dataset (the one you sent me by private email with a populated `Userdata`) most of the points are ordered but not all. For example:

```r
las@data[gpstime == 115044215.61403846741]
#>            X         Y      Z   gpstime ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns
#> 1: 537447.48 4888470.1 485.62 115044216            4               4
#> 2: 537449.40 4888469.6 492.75 115044216            3               4
#> 3: 537452.35 4888468.9 503.66 115044216            1               4
#> 4: 537450.95 4888469.2 498.46 115044216            2               4
#> 5: 537436.10 4888384.6 479.93 115044216            2               2
#> 6: 537439.94 4888384.3 493.90 115044216            1               2
```

I can't see any options that always work in this case. I'm pretty sure there is no solution.

Comment: I'm trying to see if I can group the beams by X or Y coordinates. When visually inspecting, there is a clear partitioning of Y or X coordinates. I'm tying to find if there is a threshold that can be applied to make the grouping...

Comment: This is the option I didn't want to explore. Extremely complex and yet I'm sure that it is even harder to make it robust to unexpected cases.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing that now... It would be simple to split the cases where the `NumberOfReturns` fields are different for each beam. For the cases where the `NumberOfReturns` are the same (say 5 returns for each beam), what would be the consequences of just arbitrarily splitting the 10 returns evenly into 2 beams? My current motivation for all of this (as you may know) is to supply adequate data to `sensor_tracking()` so that I can range correct my intensity values. Since I don't know how `sensor_tracking()` really works, I can't say whether or not this proposal would lead to problems...